# Is it possible to access the azerothcore game console vis SSH while the worldserver is being run by systemctl?

Tags: ssh, service, console, putty, azerothcore

I'm a longtime Windows admin and I'm trying to learn my way around Linux, but I just set up a service using `systemctl` to run `worldserver` and `authserver` so that I don't have to keep the PuTTY windows open on my computer 24/7. It's been working fine but I'd like to be able to SSH to the game server using PuTTY to quickly enter commands instead of having to launch the game and login to my GM character.

When I connect to the game server, I don't have the `AC>` prompt since I didn't run the `./worldserver` command in that session, and I'm not sure if I can just run `./worldserver` in my PuTTY session while it's simultaneously being run by `systemctl` without breaking things.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `screen` to reattach to your server console while running from a service.
To install screen on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install screen
```

- Change your service file to start a screen session:

```
ExecStart=/bin/screen -S worldserver -D -m /path/to/azerothcore/bin/worldserver
```

- Reload the services configuration (`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`)
- Restart your worldserver service (`sudo systemctl restart your-world-server.service`)
- Run `screen -r worldserver` to attach to the session
- You can now type commands in your world console
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd> to detach from the session